# Why does the confirmation window disappear in viewDidLoad?

Tags: swift

Trying to get the user's location. A confirmation window appears for 1 second and immediately disappears

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class NearbyViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

instance variable

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } 
}
```

as it's get deallocated end of `viewDidLoad` which hides the alert automatically

Comment: you mean instance property of the view controller

Comment: @LeoDabus yes , the op will get it

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the locationManager is getting deallocated when viewDidLoad completes.

Also, I would consider possibly moving to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Try this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class NearbyViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

}
```

Or this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class NearbyViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

}
```